# Switch Mac OS X system drive from USB to SATA and vice versa

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

Is it possible to remove the system drive of a MacBook, install it into an USB enclosure and boot the Mac from that? Or vice versa, is it possible to install Mac OS X onto a USB drive and later move that USB drive to the internal sata connector?

Will Mac OS X notice that the drive has moved or will it just work?

(I want to make a fresh install while still having easy access to my old install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose should work with no problems.

Comment: It worked above expectations! I installed the OS onto the usb drive and could boot between the new, ongoing install and old install at will, and when I swapped the internal and external drive with each other the mac didn't even mention it, everything just worked.